# When using pyinstaller to build a windowed python app, the unix executable works perfectly, but the .app file generated does not open

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I have an odd problem with pyinstaller when running it on macOS Sierra.

I tried to run:

```
pyinstaller program.py --windowed -w -noconsole
```

The unix executable created by this worked perfectly, though the program.app application created would not open. So I tried the following:

```
pyinstaller program.py --windowed --onefile -w -noconsole
```

Though I had the same problem. The unix executable works as expected, though the .app file does not run at all.

The files generated are just the following, where program is the unix executable:

```
program
program.app
└── Contents
    ├── Frameworks
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   └── program
    └── Resources
        └── icon-windowed.icns
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?